# Using cut on null character inside variable

Tags: bash, null-character

*GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release*

Trying to deliminate on a null character, but bash doesn't seem to keep the null character in a variable.

```
$ echo -e 'hello\0goodbye' > testlist
$ cat testlist | cut -d '' -f1
hello
$ foobar=$(echo -e 'hello\0goodbye'); echo "$foobar" | cut -d '' -f1
hellogoodbye
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that `''` is the null character?

Comment: @Miati, yes. According to my experience, shell cannot hold a null character in a variable. Other commands such as `find` and `xargs` have no problem. However, shell can even handle the null character as a part of a string, as you can see in the output of this command line: `echo -e 'A\0B' | od -tx1`

Comment: @Miati, I guess bash cannot keep the null character in a variable because it is used as the end-of-string delimiter character in C.

Answer (score 1):

Bash *does* embed the binary zero:

```
echo -e 'hello\0goodbye' | od -xc
```

gives:

```
0000000      6568    6c6c    006f    6f67    646f    7962    0a65        
       h   e   l   l   o  \0   g   o   o   d   b   y   e  \n
```

although personally I prefer the `\x00` notation.

It is the `cut` program which is the issue.  So you can use the `awk` language instead.  For example:

```
awk -F '\0'  '{print $1}' testlist
```

(note: no `cat` required)
and:

```
foobar='hello\0goodbye'
echo -e "$foobar" | awk -F '\0'  '{print $1}'
```

both give:

```
hello
```

However, `\0` is expanded to an empty string (as documented in `man bash`) so

```
foobar=$(echo -e 'hello\0goodbye')
```

looses the null, as you found.